# How to display Items that equal a value in one column and are not null in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering

Let's say I want to display all items in a table with following criteria how would i do this?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE TABLE.COLUMN1 = 'example' AND TABLE.COLUMN2 != 'NULL'
```

I want it to display all values from COLUMN1.  How does one go about this process in MS SQL?

Comment: Try using `IS NULL` to check for null values in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE TABLE.COLUMN1 = 'example' AND TABLE.COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL
```

`NULL` is an `UNKNOWN` value , you cannot use any Comparison Operators (= , <> , > , <) with it. you check for nulls like

```
ColumnName IS NULL    or ColumnName IS NOT NULL
```

If you think about it , it makes sense, to compare two or more values, you need to know the values only then you can compare them, Since SQL Server considers a NULL to be an UNKNOWN value, you cannot really compare an unknown value to anything.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` values can be compared using `IS [NOT] NULL` in SQL server. Please check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196339%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).